# Экспортуруемый класс наследуемый от не экспортируемого

Tags: c++, классы, компоновщик

В библиотеке присутствует класс, который нельзя *(не рекомендуется)* экспортировать, но необходимо от него наследоваться.

При попытке передать компоновщику такую библиотеку в которой используется не экспортируемый класс, получим ошибку компоновки.

- Как такие ситуации обходятся?
- Как правильно подойти к такой ситуации для ее решения?

```
#ifdef SOME_EXPORTS_API_ENABLED
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class some_private_class
{
private:
    // поля, методы, класс не абстрактный
public:
    some_private_class();
    virtual ~some_private_class();
};
```

```
class EXPORTS_API some_public_class : public some_private_class
{
    // поля, методы
public:
    some_public_class();
    ~some_public_class();

    // поля, методы
};
```

Comment: По-моему тут явно не хватает примера. Если экспортируемый класс наследует он неэкспортируемого, то этот "неэкспортируемый" класс на самом деле тоже экспортируемый. Если наследования нет и неэкспортируемый класс используется где-то в реализации, то никакой ошибки быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут одно из двух:

- Экспортировать `some_private_class`.
- Убрать использование определения `some_private_class` из публичных интерфейсов, ограничившись только использованием предварительного объявления. При этом для клиентского кода класс остается неполным и необходимость экспортировать его отпадет:

```
class some_private_class;

class EXPORTS_API some_public_class :{
// поля, методы
   std::unique_ptr<some_private_class> m_p_private;

public:
   some_public_class();
   ~some_public_class();

   // поля, методы
};
```